# Store `new Date ()` in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following field validator object:

```
{ type:'date', 'min':new Date() }
```

I was hoping that I could store `new Date()` as an expression in JSON and it would be executed when it's parsed

Comment: You can't store an expression in JSON and expect it to be executed when it's parsed.

Comment: Hard to tell without more context. Is it a format required by some external library? Do you generate the JSON on the server side? Woulld it be possible to refacotr the validator so it can accept an object like `{ type:'date', allowPast: false }`?

Comment: that could work, thank you @pawel

Comment: If you generate this JSON on the server you could also do something like `{ type: 'date', min: 1454680791401 }` where the time stamp is generated by your backend language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save the timestamp:

```
{ type:'date', 'min':(new Date()).getTime() }
```

then you read it back:

```
var result = JSON.parse('{ "type":"date", "min":1234567 }');
result.date = new Date(result.min);
```

Note: the server you use to serialize it and the server you use to deserialize it has to run in the same timezone

Comment: because it's field validation I was hoping I could make the `min` dynamic. So that when the page loads and sql sends this validator object it gets parsed as todays date, not a static date. Does that make sense?

Comment: no sense at all. Json is data. You save it with some value, you get it back. "dynamic" is code: you make a function and when you call it it returns the date at that moment. for this you don't need to have min in the json at all

Answer (score 3):

You can't store the complete Date object in a JSON string. But you can try to store a text representing him :

As a string :

```
{ type:'date', 'min':(new Date()).toString() }
```

As a timestamp :

```
{ type:'date', 'min':(new Date()).getTime() }
```

As an ISO string :

```
{ type:'date', 'min':(new Date()).toJSON() }
```

Comment: not working in a json file

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not support the Date datatype (it only supports string
number,
object,
array,
true,
false, and
null). You need to convert it to a string instead.

For example, ISO time:

```js
var json = JSON.stringify( { type:'date', 'min':new Date().toISOString() } );
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

The date object, actually has a `toJSON` method, which you might find useful. However I suggest using `getTime` as it returns a timestamp, which is usually more flexible.