# Saving moments to use as events in React-Big-Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I'm having trouble generating events for react big calendar. When making a new event object (in another component), I set the id, event name, just fine, and then I wonder if I'm setting start and end correctly. I'll have a moment like this (created with moment.js) `date = 05/15/2018 11:00 AM`, and when setting the start/end fields of an event I will set them as `new Date(date)`. For now I am saving this value in local storage, but it eventually will go to a database. I checked, and when I create a constant at the top of my component with my moments, and the new Date() syntax explicitly in the code it works fine, but my pre-made saved dates are not working. I am getting the following error.

```
index.js:209 Uncaught TypeError: date[("get" + method)] is not a function
    at Object.hours (index.js:209)
    at Object.isJustDate (dates.js:91)
    at TimeGrid.js:237
```

My question is how should I go about saving my moment so that it can be correctly interpreted by react big calendar?

Comment: Check the link below may be it might help ,https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/issues/163

Comment: Thank you @Praveen!

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question, [Store `new Date ()` in JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225707/store-new-date-in-json-object)

You can't store a Date as a Date in JSON, you have to convert it, so I will do so.